# Integral of exp(a/x)

Tags: integration

I know the integral of exp(ax) but couldn't find a solution for integral exp(a/x). I very appreciate if somebody help me.

Thanks
Reza

Comment: I believe it isn't expressible in terms of functions you know

Answer (score 2):

$\int e^{\frac{a}x}\mathrm{d}x$ does not resolve to any elementary form.

The closest thing I could give would be $\int e^{\frac{a}x}\mathrm{d}x=xe^{a/x}-aEi(a/x)$ where $Ei(x) =\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n\cdot n!}+ \ln(x) + \gamma$

Comment: Can you please provide some links for further reference to this?

Comment: The solution to the above can be found in [Wolfram Mathematica](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=Exp[a%2Fx]&random=false)